# How to connect to AWS MySQL database from Java?

Tags: mysql, amazon-web-services, jdbc, hikaricp

I want to connect to AWS MySQL database instance. Here is my code:

```
val hikari = HikariConfig().run {
        driverClassName = "com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"
        jdbcUrl = "jdbc:mysql://${mainConfig.databaseHost}:${mainConfig.databasePort}" +
                "?user=username&password=password"
        username = Config.DATABASE_USER
        password = Config.DATABASE_PASSWORD
        isAutoCommit = false
        transactionIsolation = "TRANSACTION_REPEATABLE_READ"
        return HikariDataSource(this)
    }

    Database.connect(hikari(config))
```

And my `mainConfig.databaseHost` looks like: `mydatabase.xyz.region.rds.amazonaws.com`.

So, this connection is working but I can't to exec any SQL statements because:

```
java.sql.SQLException: No database selected
```

I've tried to specify database name in my `jdbc` url but it causes exception.

**So how can I connect to specified AWS database?**

Comment: It causes *what* exception? And what is the code that you used that caused that exception? As your question is written, the only answer that anyone can give is "you need to add the database name into the URL."

Comment: @Parsifal you right! After little research I found that DB identifier and DB name are different

Answer (score 0):

After research I found that DB identifier and DB name are different, so I specified DB name in `jdbc` url and now it working!